# multi-domain recognition at db level

Tags: 8, multi-sites

I have:

- 2 domains
- single database
- Single codebase
- single form with a text-editor and submit button.

What I want is the recognition of domain at database level. So, let's say if I hit http://example.com/en it should save in db with table **T1** and if I hit http://example.fr/en it should also save in same db but with different table **T2**.

And now when I will fetch default value from table **T1**, it should only reflect to http://example.com/en and similarly for **T2** it goes here - http://example.fr/en.

But because of **same database and code base** of both domains it is difficult to know from which domain the request is coming.

I have **1 solution is** like create a table in `.install` file by considering `global $base_url;` and then check if table name = `$base_url.my_table` exists, fetch all results.But I'm not sure it's the best approach in Drupal 8 or some other way to achieve this.

Please share best approach for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable multisite.

The documentation inside the settings.php file is also very helpful, read that too by viewing the source of the file here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!default!default.settings.php/8.

Briefly, the steps are,

1. Multi-site requires the existence of the sites/sites.php file in your Drupal 8 installation. You will need to create this file manually.

Example content would be:

```
<?php
$sites['mysite.com'] = 'site1';
$sites['8000.localhost'] = 'site2';
```

2. Create a site directory inside sites/, the path should be sites/site1.
   Put a settings.php file in this directory in order for Drupal 8 to recognize it.
3. Visit the URL of site1, like mysite.com to install it.

Comment: This question was tagged with `8`. Meaning it's for Drupal 8 not 7.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect Drupal8 instead of Drupal7